# Formatting a sharepoint list view

Tags: json, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am trying to do a couple of things in a sharepoint list but not getting anywhere. I wondered if you could help.

I am trying to firstly - work it so when someone hits the 'Submit' button (renaming of the 'exitGridView') it not only saves the submission but redirects to another url? Is that possible with only using the custom JSON editor in sharepoint?

Secondly, it would be great if we could remove the 'Add new item' when in grid view so they can only see whats already there. again is this possible in the same way?

so far the JSON looks like this:

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": {
    "operator": ":",
    "operands": [
      {
        "operator": "==",
        "operands": [
          {
            "operator": "%",
            "operands": [
              "@rowIndex",
              2
            ]
          },
          0
        ]
      },
      "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgLightGray30",
      {
        "operator": ":",
        "operands": [
          {
            "operator": "==",
            "operands": [
              {
                "operator": "%",
                "operands": [
                  "@rowIndex",
                  2
                ]
              },
              1
            ]
          },
          "sp-css-backgroundColor-noFill",
          ""
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "commandBarProps": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "key": "exitGridView",
        "text": "Submit"
      },
      {
        "key": "editInGridView",
        "text": "Edit"
      },
      {
        "key": "new",
        "hide": true
      },
      {
        "key": "export",
        "hide": true
      },
      {
        "key": "automate",
        "hide": true
      },
      {
        "key": "share",
        "hide": true
      },
      {
        "key": "integrate",
        "hide": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Is it possible to redirect to another URL after click on the exitGridView button using view formatting?

- As far I know unfortunately it is not possible

2. Is it possible to hide Add new item in Command bar?

- Yes, it is possible. You can hide buttons on Command bar, change text or icon and many more. You will find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-commandbar-formatting)

Please do not forget mark this as answer if it helps you.